# How can I create a marquee effect?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm creating a marquee effect with CSS3 animation.

```css
#caption {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height:30px;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -moz-animation:  caption 50s linear 0s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:  caption 50s linear 0s infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes caption { 
    0% { margin-left:120%; } 100% { margin-left:-4200px; }  
}
@-webkit-keyframes caption { 
    0% { margin-left:120%; } 100% { margin-left:-4200px; }  
}
```

```html
<div id="caption">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>
```

Now I can get the basic marquee effect, but the code is too specific for this demo.

Is there a way to avoid using specific values like `margin-left:-4200px;`, so that it can adapt text in any length?

Here is a similar demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/XxUXD/ that uses `text-indent` but still with specific values.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

With a small change of the markup, here's my approach (I've just inserted a `span` inside the paragraph):

```css
.marquee {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: max-content;

  padding-left: 100%;
  /* show the marquee just outside the paragraph */
  will-change: transform;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}


@keyframes marquee {
  0% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}


/* Respect user preferences about animations */

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .marquee span {
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 0.01; 
    /* instead of animation: none, so an animationend event is 
     * still available, if previously attached.
     */
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">
   <span>
       When I had journeyed half of our life's way, I found myself
       within a shadowed forest, for I had lost the path that 
       does not stray. – (Dante Alighieri, <i>Divine Comedy</i>. 
       1265-1321)
   </span>
   </p>
```

---

No hardcoded values — dependent on paragraph width  — have been inserted.

The animation applies the CSS3 `transform` property (use prefixes where needed) so it performs well.

If you need to insert a delay just once at the beginning then also set an `animation-delay`. If you need instead to insert a small delay at *every* loop then try to play with an higher `padding-left` (e.g. `150%`)

Comment: This did not work for me when I tried it on my site. I found out that there's an external resource [prefixfree.js](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/prefixfree.js) that's needed. I should have noticed the (1) beside external resources on the jsfiddle page. For those who just copied the above text without going there, you'll need the prefixfree javascript file too.

Comment: of course, you need to add vendor prefixes where necessary.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Thank you, but just wondering.. Is it possible to detect if the text has finished scrolling with some javascript?

Comment: I twisted it a little so that instead of starting on the right, it starts with the first text already positioned left. Small change:
add `.marquee span { animation-delay: -7.5s; }`

Comment: @fcalderan It it possible to make the animation without trailing space? I mean the second animation start before the 1st animation is finish so that no blank space between the animation. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice but if the text character gets more or less, the speed changes as well. The more text, the faster text. Is there a solution for it? @fcalderan

Comment: @YasinOkumuş try to increase the animation-duration

Comment: This answer worked, sort of,  If you are experiencing weird behaviour like: Text slows down when fully in view (even with `linear`) or: When using text-indent: -100% the text stops at ~50%. You might have the css tag: `text-align: center` on. It causes weird stuff to happen. Just wanted to add it here in case anyone had problems like I had.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the previous reply, mainly @fcalderan, this marquee scrolls when hovered, with the advantage that the animation scrolls completely even if the text is shorter than the space within it scrolls, also any text length takes the same amount of time (this may be a pros or a cons) when not hovered the text return in the initial position.

No hardcoded value other than the scroll time, best suited for small scroll spaces

```css
.marquee {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-flex;    
}

.marquee span {
    display: flex;        
    flex-basis: 100%;
    animation: marquee-reset;
    animation-play-state: paused;                
}

.marquee:hover> span {
    animation: marquee 2s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0%, 0);
    }    
    50% {
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
    50.001% {
        transform: translate(100%, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0%, 0);
    }
}
@keyframes marquee-reset {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0%, 0);
    }  
}
```

```html
<span class="marquee">
    <span>This is the marquee text (hover the mouse here)</span>
</span>
```

Comment: A tip for future readers: **hover the text in the demo**.

Answer (score 2):

**The accepted answers animation does not work on Safari**, I've updated it using translate instead of padding-left which makes for a smoother, bulletproof animation.

Also, the accepted answers demo fiddle has a lot of unnecessary styles.

So I created a simple version if you just want to cut and paste the useful code and not spend 5 mins clearing through the demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/e8ws12pt/

```css
.marquee {
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    height: 16px;
    display: block;
}
.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 15s;
    transition: 15s;
    -webkit-animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% { transform: translate(100%, 0); -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee"><span>Simple CSS Marquee - Lorem ipsum dolor amet tattooed squid microdosing taiyaki cardigan polaroid single-origin coffee iPhone. Edison bulb blue bottle neutra shabby chic. Kitsch affogato you probably haven't heard of them, keytar forage plaid occupy pitchfork. Enamel pin crucifix tilde fingerstache, lomo unicorn chartreuse plaid XOXO yr VHS shabby chic meggings pinterest kickstarter.</span></p>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the heads-up regarding safari, but one question: if you're saying you're cleaning up the extra styles... why adding "padding: 0; height: 16px; and stuff like that? Is it for some browsers to display correctly? Thank you!

Comment: I'm testing on Safari Version 13.1.1 and the accepted answer works fine (OSX Mojave, October 2020)

Comment: Feels like bullet train :D

Answer (score -1):

The following should do what you want.

```
@keyframes marquee {
    from  { text-indent:  100% }
    to    { text-indent: -100% }
}
```

Comment: No it does not, since the parent width is considered for this: Let it scroll to the end and see that the text disappears before it is scrolled completely out of sight: http://jsfiddle.net/XxUXD/712/

Comment: I just up voted your comments, you're right... nobody told me it runs infinite. ;)