# Get rid of marquee padding

Tags: html, css, marquee

Is there anyway to get rid of the marquee padding? I was never able to figure this out, I know you can change the width and height but what about padding? I'm trying to change the amount of space between the wording and the top and bottom.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag2t5/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<marquee width="50%">
    <p>Sample ticker text goes here</p>
</marquee>
```

**CSS**

```
marquee {
    font-family: wallStreetFont;
    font-size:50px;
    color:red;
    background-color: black; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;

}
```

Comment: It's 2014 and somebody is still using marquee?

Comment: is this a *retro* website? Maybe this could help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee 
BTW you can achieve a marquee like effect with CSS3. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233033/css3-marquee-effect

Comment: You should avoid using `<marquee>` because it is **non-standard** and **obsolete** - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0

Comment: ah thanks I appreciate all the feed back!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the `marquee`, it's the `p` tag that has the padding (margin, in this case).

So:

```
p { margin: 0; }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag2t5/3/)