# Marquee data list with multiple colors

Tags: jquery, css, razor

I'm trying to implement a marquee with  colors that change depending on the value. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233033/css3-marquee-effect) and I have my marquee up and running. The issue I'm having is with the razor html.

**Partial** This throws everything into one span so I'm sure how to change each item's color

```
@model IEnumerable<ticker.Models.ProcBookingsModel>

<p class="marqueeTop">
    <span>
        @foreach(var item in Model){
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.GroupName);
                @ViewBag.Space;
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Sales);         
        }
    </span>
</p>
```

I thought something like this would work but it doesn't seem to (up changes it to green)

```
<p class="marqueeTop">
    <span>
        @foreach(var item in Model){
            if (item.Sales > 100000)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.GroupName, new {@class = "up"});
                @ViewBag.Space;
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Sales , new {@class = "up"});   
            }      
        }
    </span>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.up {
    color: #4F692A;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setColors();

});

function setColors() {
    $('.totalSales').each(function () {

        if (final > 100000) {
            $(this).addClass('up');
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Seems to work fine if you remove the "final" variable check: http://jsfiddle.net/67uhaur7/ How does it get computed?

Comment: Thanks it was definitely as simple as that. I was unaware of the label tag.... Add this as the answer and I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine if you remove the "final" variable check: http://jsfiddle.net/67uhaur7/ How does it get computed?

```
function setColors() {
    $('.totalSales').each(function () {

            $(this).addClass('up');
    });
}
```