# Marquee div in flex

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, marquee

I'm trying to create an infinite horizontal "scroll" like a marquee effect ([like this one](http://jsfiddle.net/1mjfwvu8/2/), for example).

This is my code:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 10%;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}

.child1 {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #84B7DF;
}
.child2 {
  width: 18rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f58db6;
}
.child3 {
  width: 13rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffc410;
}
.child4 {
  width: 21rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #C8E7C1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it works but not perfectly.
I would like that as soon as the green rectangle has shifted, the blue (slightly spaced) one immediately appears, I don't want there to ever be a whole white screen.

I hope is clear what I mean...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to manually loop the elements. Which means duplicating the ones of the beginning and appending it to the back. You do that on and on and then you have the effect.

Comment: Adjust the widths of  the `.child` elements in such a way that their sum equals to the width of `.container`

Comment: @Nimsrules Can you give me an example? That is a simple example, suppose I don't have fixed width of children elements, but their width depends on their content..

Comment: @CodeSpirit Can you post an example?

Comment: Check out this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433961/css3-marquee-effect-without-empty-space

Answer (score 2):

You could just add one more container element with same children, and then use `display: flex` with `overflow: hidden` on parent element. Also you can set width of the `.container` element to be larger then the window width using `vw` units and `flex` property.

Adjust `width` and `padding` properties on `container` if you have to.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 120vw;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 10%;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}

.child1 {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #84B7DF;
}

.child2 {
  width: 18rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f58db6;
}

.child3 {
  width: 13rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffc410;
}

.child4 {
  width: 21rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #C8E7C1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container other">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to add `padding-right` width `vw` units on `container`.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}

.child1 {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #84B7DF;
}

.child2 {
  width: 18rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f58db6;
}

.child3 {
  width: 13rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffc410;
}

.child4 {
  width: 21rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #C8E7C1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container other">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript / jQuery solution, you can first create clone of the original element and append it to parent. Create a function that will decrease left position of the elements with `setInterval` function. If the offset is less then `-width` of the same element that means that element is off the screen. In that case you should move element to the end of the window or to the end of the other element with some offset.

```js
const parent = $(".parent");
const container = $(".container");
const offset = 250;

const clone = cloner(container, parent, offset);

function cloner(element, parent, offset) {
  const clone = element.clone();
  const width = element.width();

  clone.css({left: width + offset})
  parent.append(clone)
  return clone;
}

function move(element, size = 1) {
  const position = element.position().left;
  const width = element.width();

  if (position < -width) {
    const next = element.siblings().first();
    const nPosition = next.position().left;
    const nWidth = next.width();
    const wWidth = $(window).width();

    if (nPosition + nWidth < wWidth) {
      element.css({left: wWidth})
    } else {
      element.css({left: nPosition + nWidth + offset})
    }

  } else {
    element.css({left: position - size})
  }
}

window.mover = setInterval(() => {
  move(container)
  move(clone)
}, 5)
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.parent>div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.child1 {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #84B7DF;
}

.child2 {
  width: 18rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f58db6;
}

.child3 {
  width: 13rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffc410;
}

.child4 {
  width: 21rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #C8E7C1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not a good solution. Test it in a large screen.. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1powjOI_n8QUtzdfOP-OODvgOlEbJ8opi

Comment: @Buster You could set width of the container to be larger then window width with `flex`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: Can yoy explain better what `flex: 0 0 120vw;` means? Why `120vw`?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex, `120vw` is just random pick, the point is that it is larger then window, you should customize those based on your actual example and animation speed and padding.

Comment: I test you code in a codepen. In my case screen width is 1300 so I use `1300vw` and greater values than `1300`. In each case it doesn't work. What I'm wrong?

Comment: `100vw` is full window width so `1300vw` is `window width * 13`

Comment: @Buster I've added another solution with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
.marquee {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    > div {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        > * {
            display: inline;
            white-space: nowrap;
            &:last-child {
                padding-right: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```