# vertical content scrolling continue without marque

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just to move vertical text from top to bottom but no need to gap. like one paragraph is over then after text continue behind the first text ended.

[image]

```css
  * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Roboto Mono';
    }
    .title-verticle {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
        height: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        padding: 0 0.8vw;
        width: 3.6vw;
    }
    .title-verticle p {
        -webkit-transform: scale(-1);
        transform: scale(-1);
        text-align: center;
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        font-size: 1.1vw;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 120%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .title-verticle marquee {
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="title-verticle">
       <p> 
         <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" loop="infinite">
            We help brands and companies understand their audience through research and data driven.  
         </marquee>
       </p> 
    </div>
```

Note: Please help me out. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Your question makes very little sense and it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Could you please edit the question to give it some clarity.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please read and give me solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan he means he wants to start marquee without gape. like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433961/css3-marquee-effect-without-empty-space but he wants it vertically.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for updating but I want the vertical text to rotate from top to bottom continue. please give me a solution.