# Infinite horizontal animation: how make it smooth?

Tags: css, css-animations

I've made a basic text animation where text is going from left to right.It works smoothly but when last span gets to 100% it jumps straight to 0% without any transition.

Here a little snippet of what I have at the moment. Oh and is there any way to remove the little glitch we can see on text during this animation?

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  animation: left-to-right-animation 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes left-to-right-animation {
  0%  { transform: translate(-20%, 0%);}
  100%{ transform: translate(120%, 0%);}
}

.title{
  width: 100%;
}

p.about {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 400;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <div class="title">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="about">Text 1</p>
      <p class="about">Text 2</p>
      <p class="about">Text 3</p>
      <p class="about">Text 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433961/css3-marquee-effect-without-empty-space