# How can I create a responsive (mobile, tablet, and desktop) custom marquee?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, marquee

**Requirements**:

- Marquee content should be multiple images
- Marquee will slide from right to left infinitely
- There will be no white space or space when the marquee ends
- Must be responsive for mobile, tablet, and desktop
- Must be made using only HTML and CSS

Can anyone help me to create this? I tried with built-in HTML marquee tags and other custom marquees. But, none of these fulfill the above requirements.

I tried with the followings.

- [How to create a CSS marquee effect without empty space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433961/how-to-create-a-css-marquee-effect-without-empty-space)

Comment: What's your HTML? CSS? JavaScript? Where's the code that you wrote, that didn't work? Where did that code fail?

Comment: @DavidThomas [Here](https://codepen.io/imRHB/pen/xxQJvQG) is my current HTML and CSS (SCSS)