# Text slideshow with effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, slideshow

I have an issue with text slideshow. I want to make it slide to the left side of the div and make the new text slide from the right side. I tried few examples I found here, but nothing worked, except for one that basicaly broke the look of the page. This is my setup:

```
<div>
    <p id="textslide"></p>
</div>
```

```js
var quotes = [ "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" ];
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    $("#textslide").html(quotes[i]);
    if (i == quotes.length) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}, 10 * 700);
```

Any ideas on how to make the slide effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very Simple, Very Smooth, JavaScript Marquee](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee)

Comment: or in pure css: [css3-marquee-effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233033/css3-marquee-effect)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be using a marquee

```
<marquee class='marquee'></marquee>
```

You can then write the javascript as follows.

```
var quotes = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"];
$.each(quotes, function(i, j) {
  $("marquee.marquee").append('<span>'+j+'</span>')
})
```

you can even give individual elements (`span` in this case) style

```
.marquee span{
  margin:10px;
}
```