# How to make marquee text only when it's overflowing?

Tags: html, css, marquee

I have a text which is generated randomly to a div. And this text has different width depending on what is currently generated. And I want this text to marquee **only when is too big.** html:

```
<div id="random_word"> <!--here appears something--> </div>
```

css:

```
#random_word {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8vw;
    margin-top: 22%;
    font-variant: small-caps
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

I found already this css property in internet: `overflow-x:-webkit-marquee;`
but I'm not sure how to use it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe [CSS3 Marquee Effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233033/css3-marquee-effect) combined with [Check with jquery if div has overflowing elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7668636/1456376)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to determine if an element is overflowing is to compare its `scroll` height/width to its `offset` height/width. If any of the `scroll` values are larger than their `offset` pairs, your element's contents are overflowing.

```
function isElementOverflowing(element) {
    var overflowX = element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth,
        overflowY = element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight;

    return (overflowX || overflowY);
}
```

From here it's a simple question of checking the return value of this function and adding a marquee effect if `true`. To achieve this, you can wrap your div's contents in a `<marquee>`, or achieve the same visual effect using the prefixed `marquee` CSS rules or simulating it via a CSS animation.

*NB: while the `<marquee>` tag still works as expected in most browsers, it is considered deprecated hence not futureproof.*

- Here is [a quick fiddle on wrapping in a marquee tag](https://jsfiddle.net/ppajer/zeuzzguk/), play around with text length to see how it works. (alternatively, you can set the marquee's behavior to alternate from side to side: [here's how](https://jsfiddle.net/ppajer/zeuzzguk/1/) )
- here is [a tutorial on CSS marquee](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-marquee/)
- and here is [a thread on visually simulating a marquee with animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233033/css3-marquee-effect)

Good luck!

Comment: Oh men, thanks. But I have one more question. How to make this (https://jsfiddle.net/ppajer/zeuzzguk/) marquee's behavior alternate. I mean  I want it to bounce from the right to the left and than again to the right and so on.

Comment: @kupkol You can control it through the `behavior` attribute. `<marquee behavior="alternate">` will achieve a bouncing effect.

Comment: Ooh sorry, it's injected via JS. That would be `marquee.behavior = "alternate";`, [updated the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppajer/zeuzzguk/1/)

Comment: Hey, I'm having this problem right now, could you please tell me how I can make it vertical though?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the accepted answer is working when the overflow is hidden.

Better add another div inside and check their widths
[Check with jquery if div has overflowing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements/60624293#60624293)