# The <marquee> is block element or inline element?

Tags: html, css, marquee

I write a html/css code, and find the `<marquee>` and `<span>`'s layout is strange:

[image]

if `<marquee>` is a inline element, the `span` will on the right of the `marquee`, but if I use the `span` float right, it will like this:

[image]

So the `<marquee>` is not a block element.

How does the `<marquee>` display in html?

Comment: The marquee is a "non-standard element". Don't use it! https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee

Comment: @MichaelCoker Is there a substitution of the marquee element? I can get the effect.

Comment: @MichaelCoker And if the marquee is a non-standard element, can I use a div to warp it, and use the div ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233033/css3-marquee-effect

Comment: "The <marquee> is block element or inline element?" - more like a dead element :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should avoid to use this tag: It's not a standard element. See yourself: 
https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee

To replace it, you should use some javascript, or use a plugin :

https://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

You can achieve to do that in pure css to with animations : 
http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/EjMBqO

```
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```