# Is it possible to recreate marquee using CSS only?

Tags: css, html, css-animations, marquee

I have a requirement that can be solved using a marquee

```css
.ticker {
  white-space: no-wrap;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<marquee class="ticker" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
 </marquee>
```

How do we make this compliant with html5 since marquee is deprecated?

I have seen a few examples, but most of them rely on fixed width.
In my example, the items are received from the server so there can be a lot of them. Also, I will need that stop on hover since the items are links to something else.

Thank you very much for your help,

PS: I want to make sure we can't do this in CSS only before I start exploring javascript.

Comment: Never tried to add something similar, but maybe this will help -> https://www.thoughtco.com/scrollable-content-html5-css3-without-marquee-3467007

Comment: Yes, its possible.  Search for 'CSS3 marquee' and you get lots of results.

Comment: Morpheus, I tried to add those styles to a <div/> and it does not work. I tested in IE11 and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found one that works, and here is the finally product https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/228u

Here is the original one, https://codepen.io/lewismcarey/pen/GJZVoG

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
       <span>Span Me 1</span>
       <span>Span Me 2</span>
       <span>Span Me 3</span>
       <span>Span Me 4</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The trick was to "left-pad" the wrapper to hide the container initially. Then, "right-pad" the container so that the animation only stops/restarts once the container has gone off screen. Both padding are sized relatively. `display: block;` is added to the container so that the right padding uses the wrapper's size. And finally, we add an animation on the wrapper's transform attribute.

Thank you all,

Answer (score 10):

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa) has a great example of what you're looking for.

To make it pause on hover, I added a hover state to pause the animation: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzpZyg

```
   .marquee:hover div {
      -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }
```

```css
body { margin: 20px; }

.marquee {
  height: 25px;
  width: 420px;

  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 30px;

  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;

  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}

.marquee:hover div {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div>
    <span>You spin me right round, baby. Like a record, baby.</span>
    <span>You spin me right round, baby. Like a record, baby.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If we add more <span/> element to that example it does not work like a marquee.

Comment: @herme0 you can sort that by adding `white-space: nowrap` to `.marquee div {}` and removing styles for `.marquee span`

Comment: I did that in the codepen sample, then replaced the inner html with
<span>Another span 1</span><span>Another span 1</span>...<span>Another span 15</span> it resets the scrolling once it hits span #10. I think it is because of the width: 300% on .marquee div {}.

Comment: @herme0 Right, now I am with you. It is because the animation is being repeated from the initial point `left: 0` after 5 seconds

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I know I am late. However, I have a simple solution to create a marquee with CSS.

```css
.marquee-container{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.marquee{
  min-width:100%;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}
.marquee:hover{
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  from{margin-left : 120%;}
    to{margin-left: -20%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee-container">
    <p class="marquee">
      <span>Item 1</span>
      <span>Item 2</span>
      <span>Item 3</span>
      <span>Item 4</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am no good at java script

but here is it using html and css

PS. that mouse over thing is not working here

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.wrapper p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Hey, how you're doing? .</p>
</div>
```

Comment: My example has multiple items inside the wrapper. Adding more items to the example you gave will stack the text on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of information on google about it, just search: "css3 marque", like Neil Kennedy mentioned. One question is very similar to yours and the text stops scrolling after you hover over it. Check this link below: [CSS3 Marquee Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233033/css3-marquee-effect) and jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MaY5A/1/

```js
$(".toggle").on("click", function() {
  $(".marquee").toggleClass("microsoft");
});
```

```css
/* Make it a marquee */

.marquee {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px green solid;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  text-indent: 0;
  border: 1px red solid;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}


/* Make it move */

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}


/* Make it pretty */

.microsoft {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  font: 16px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}


/* ::before was :before before ::before was ::before - kthx */

.microsoft:before,
.microsoft::before {
  z-index: 2;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  left: -1em;
  width: .5em;
  height: .5em;
  box-shadow: 1.0em 1.25em 0 #F65314, 1.6em 1.25em 0 #7CBB00, 1.0em 1.85em 0 #00A1F1, 1.6em 1.85em 0 #FFBB00;
}

.microsoft:after,
.microsoft::after {
  z-index: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, white 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}


/* Style the links */

.vanity {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  font: .75em 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.vanity a,
.microsoft a {
  color: #1570A6;
  transition: color .5s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vanity a:hover,
.microsoft a:hover {
  color: #F65314;
}


/* Style toggle button */

.toggle {
  display: block;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Wanted to see how easily marquees could be constructed with CSS:
     - This demo uses -prefix-free to avoid vendor prefixes
     - It also requires manual setting of the end text-indent
     - Everything below the /* Make it pretty */ comment is non-essential
     - Brought to you by @jonathansampson -->
<p class="microsoft marquee"><span>Windows 8 and Windows RT are focused on your life—your friends and family, your apps, and your stuff. With new things like the <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/start-screen">Start screen</a>, <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/charms">charms</a>, and a <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/microsoft-account">Microsoft account</a>, you can spend less time searching and more time doing.</span></p>
<button class="toggle">Toggle Beautification</button>
<p class="vanity">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/jonathansampson">@jonathansampson</a> of
  <a href="https://twitter.com/appendTo">@appendTo</a>
</p>
```

Comment: The accepted solution in the post does not work once we have multiple <span/> inside the marquee element.