# Infinitely rolling text with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

On my HTML page, I need to have a line with text that rolls "infinitely" on  the page, e.g.

"Hello World ... Hello World ... Hello World ... Hello World ..."

Sort of like a ticker tape, but with the same text's beginning rolling into its end w/o a gap.

I've tried using **animation: marquee** CSS style, I can get the text roll, then jump back, then roll again, but that's not what I need.

Is this possible with CSS? JS would be OK, if there is a working solution.

Comment: I don't think its possible only with css. But with js, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee).

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233033/css3-marquee-effect

Comment: It's outdated, but you could go old school with the marquee element... Here's an example `<marquee bgcolor="#cccccc" loop="-1" direction="right" scrollamount="2" width="100%">Horizontally Scrolling Marquee</marquee>`

[Here it is in action.](https://www.codeply.com/go/URsa9kT9wO)

Comment: yuriy636,  cwanjt, thanks! I saw those, and they are the "start from the beginning" kind. Until the text scrolls all the way, the next iteration does not start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try here "text rolling" working with text & images and mouse effects(js+css)

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Comment: Really? it was my fault not yours spending time to help!, did you check text how act???????

Comment: Apart from catbadgers comment, we usually prefer that you take the relevant part of your source and place that in your answer/jsFiddle. That way, if you sources no longer exists you have the relevant content in your answer (instead of a dead link).

Comment: @Martijn Yes, you are right , but his comment was sick " 
This does not answer the question asked"

Comment: Yes, but what he probally ment was what I said, I just said it a bit more polite haha :) learning how to comment is also a part of the process

Comment: Dreamer, thank you, your answer was closest to helping me, in fact, apart from a script that's a bit hard to understand / customize, it does exactly what I need. Voted up plus marking as answered.

Comment: @user2349195 ,happy that i could help :))

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to using a lib that does this?

This one here: http://www.cssscript.com/marquee-like-horizontal-scroller-with-pure-javascript-marquee-js/ does a good job.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  new Marquee('example', {
    // once or continuous
    continuous: true,
    // 'rtl' or 'ltr'
    direction: 'rtl',
    // pause between loops
    delayAfter: 1000,
    // when to start
    delayBefore: 0,
    // scroll speed
    speed: 0.5,
    // loops
    loops: -1
  });
});

////////////////////////////// LIBRARY BELOW ///////

// See: http://www.cssscript.com/marquee-like-horizontal-scroller-with-pure-javascript-marquee-js/
/*
 Vanilla Javascript Marquee
 Version: 0.1.0
 Author: Robert Bossaert <https://github.com/robertbossaert>
 Example call:
 
 new Marquee('element');
 new Marquee('element', {
  direction: 'rtl',
 });
*/
var Marquee = function(element, defaults) {
  "use strict";

  var elem = document.getElementById(element),
    options = (defaults === undefined) ? {} : defaults,
    continuous = options.continuous || true, // once or continuous
    delayAfter = options.delayAfter || 1000, // pause between loops
    delayBefore = options.delayBefore || 0, // when to start
    direction = options.direction || 'ltr', // ltr or rtl
    loops = options.loops || -1,
    speed = options.speed || 0.5,
    timer = null,
    milestone = 0,
    marqueeElem = null,
    elemWidth = null,
    self = this,
    ltrCond = 0,
    loopCnt = 0,
    start = 0,
    process = null,
    constructor = function(elem) {

      // Build html
      var elemHTML = elem.innerHTML,
        elemNode = elem.childNodes[1] || elem;

      elemWidth = elemNode.offsetWidth;

      marqueeElem = '<div>' + elemHTML + '</div>';
      elem.innerHTML = marqueeElem;
      marqueeElem = elem.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
      elem.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      marqueeElem.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
      marqueeElem.style.position = 'relative';

      if (continuous === true) {
        marqueeElem.innerHTML += elemHTML;
        marqueeElem.style.width = '200%';

        if (direction === 'ltr') {
          start = -elemWidth;
        }
      } else {
        ltrCond = elem.offsetWidth;

        if (direction === 'rtl') {
          milestone = ltrCond;
        }
      }

      if (direction === 'ltr') {
        milestone = -elemWidth;
      } else if (direction === 'rtl') {
        speed = -speed;
      }

      self.start();

      return marqueeElem;
    }

  this.start = function() {
    process = window.setInterval(function() {
      self.play();
    });
  };

  this.play = function() {
    // beginning
    marqueeElem.style.left = start + 'px';
    start = start + speed;

    if (start > ltrCond || start < -elemWidth) {
      start = milestone;
      loopCnt++;

      if (loops !== -1 && loopCnt >= loops) {
        marqueeElem.style.left = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  this.end = function() {
    window.clearInterval(process);
  }

  // Init plugin
  marqueeElem = constructor(elem);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #edf3f9;
  color: #3f4f5f;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3f4f5f;
  padding: 6.25em 0 3.95em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.example {
  padding: 3em 0;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

pre {
  background: #f5f2f0;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', monospace;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 1em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

pre span.string {
  color: #690;
}

pre span.number {
  color: #905;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  The quick brown fox ran over to the bar to drink some water. He walked up to the bar tender and said: blah blah blah.
</div>
```

Comment: I just looked more closely at how he's doing this and I there is a noticeable jump in the letters at one point unfortunately. Therefore I'd look for other libs that do this (I'm going to do some searches as well - I'm sure there is a lot out there). The lib above uses javascript to continuously update the DOM on a timer. I wonder if there is a more elegant solution out there that uses CSS transforms instead

Comment: Thanks, flyer, yes, there is a jump, like you said. @Dreamer's sample actually does what I want, though still struggling to customize to my needs.

Comment: Oh good. Yeah that one works better. I posted a demo using it b/c he only provided a link to the library. Are your struggles related to styling it properly? I didn't like how the lib put unnecessary styles (some are necessary for the effect) on the element so I removed it from the crawler code in my demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo based upon the lib that **Dreamer** posted. 
I didn't like how it set inline styles on the element or how it used cookies to store past settings so I removed that in the crawler.js code.

This is a pretty old library (ie5 is mentioned (!)) but it seems to do the trick.

```js
$(function() {

  marqueeInit({
    uniqueid: 'mycrawler',
    style: {
      
    },
    inc: 5, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
    mouse: 'cursor driven', //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
    moveatleast: 2,
    neutral: 150,
    persist: true,
    savedirection: true
  });
});

//////////////// CRAWLER.JS FOLLOWS ///////////

/* Text and/or Image Crawler Script v1.53 (c)2009-2012 John Davenport Scheuer
   as first seen in http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/
   username: jscheuer1 - This Notice Must Remain for Legal Use
   updated: 4/2011 for random order option, more (see below)
   */

/* Update 4/2011 to v1.5 - Adds optional random property. Set it to true to use.
   Fixes browser crash from empty crawlers, ad and image blocking software/routines.
   Fixes behavior in some IE of breaking script if an image is missing.
   Adds alt attributes to images without them to aid in diagnosis of missing/corrupt
   images. This may be disabled with the new optional noAddedAlt property set to true.
   Internal workings enhanced for greater speed of execution, less memory usage.
   */

/* Update 11/2011 - Detect and randomize td elements within a single table with a single tr */

// updated 7/2012 to 1.51 for optional integration with 3rd party initializing scripts -
// ref: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?p=278161#post278161
// updated 8/2012 to 1.52 for greater compatibility with IE in Quirks Mode

/* Update 10/2012 to v1.53 - Adds optional persist property to have the crawler remember its
   position and direction page to page and on page reload. To enable it in the marqueeInit set
   persist: true,
   */

///////////////// No Need to Edit - Configuration is Done in the On Page marqueeInit call(s) /////////////////


function marqueeInit(config) {
  if (!document.createElement) return;
  marqueeInit.ar.push(config);
  marqueeInit.run(config.uniqueid);
}

(function() {

  if (!document.createElement) return;

  if (typeof opera === 'undefined') {
    window.opera = false;
  }

  marqueeInit.ar = [];

  document.write('<style type="text/css">.marquee{white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;}' +
    '#marq_kill_marg_bord{border:none!important;margin:0!important;}<\/style>');
  var c = 0,
    tTRE = [/^\s*$/, /^\s*/, /\s*$/, /[^\/]+$/],
    req1 = {
      'position': 'relative',
      'overflow': 'hidden'
    },
    defaultconfig = {
      style: { //default style object for marquee containers without configured style
        'margin': '0 auto'
      },
      direction: 'left',
      inc: 2, //default speed - pixel increment for each iteration of a marquee's movement
      mouse: 'pause' //default mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
    },
    dash, ie = false,
    oldie = 0,
    ie5 = false,
    iever = 0;

  /*@cc_on @*/
  /*@if(@_jscript_version >= 5)
  ie = true;
  try{document.documentMode = 2000}catch(e){};
  iever = Math.min(document.documentMode, navigator.appVersion.replace(/^.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+).*$/, '$1'));
  if(iever < 6)
   oldie = 1;
  if(iever < 5.5){
   Array.prototype.push = function(el){this[this.length] = el;};
   ie5 = true;
   dash = /(-(.))/;
   String.prototype.encamel = function(s, m){
    s = this;
    while((m = dash.exec(s)))
     s = s.replace(m[1], m[2].toUpperCase());
    return s;
   };
  }
  @end @*/

  if (!ie5) {
    dash = /-(.)/g;

    function toHump(a, b) {
      return b.toUpperCase();
    };
    String.prototype.encamel = function() {
      return this.replace(dash, toHump);
    };
  }

  if (ie && iever < 8) {
    marqueeInit.table = [];
    window.attachEvent('onload', function() {
      marqueeInit.OK = true;
      var i = -1,
        limit = marqueeInit.table.length;
      while (++i < limit)
        marqueeInit.run(marqueeInit.table[i]);
    });
  }

  function intable(el) {
    while ((el = el.parentNode))
      if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'table')
        return true;
    return false;
  };

  marqueeInit.run = function(id) {
    if (ie && !marqueeInit.OK && iever < 8 && intable(document.getElementById(id))) {
      marqueeInit.table.push(id);
      return;
    }
    if (!document.getElementById(id))
      setTimeout(function() {
        marqueeInit.run(id);
      }, 300);
    else
      new Marq(c++, document.getElementById(id));
  }

  function trimTags(tag) {
    var r = [],
      i = 0,
      e;
    while ((e = tag.firstChild) && e.nodeType === 3 && tTRE[0].test(e.nodeValue))
      tag.removeChild(e);
    while ((e = tag.lastChild) && e.nodeType === 3 && tTRE[0].test(e.nodeValue))
      tag.removeChild(e);
    if ((e = tag.firstChild) && e.nodeType === 3)
      e.nodeValue = e.nodeValue.replace(tTRE[1], '');
    if ((e = tag.lastChild) && e.nodeType === 3)
      e.nodeValue = e.nodeValue.replace(tTRE[2], '');
    while ((e = tag.firstChild))
      r[i++] = tag.removeChild(e);
    return r;
  }

  function randthem(tag) {
    var els = oldie ? tag.all : tag.getElementsByTagName('*'),
      i = els.length,
      childels = [];
    while (--i > -1) {
      if (els[i].parentNode === tag) {
        childels.push(els[i]);
      }
    }
    childels.sort(function() {
      return 0.5 - Math.random();
    });
    i = childels.length;
    while (--i > -1) {
      tag.appendChild(childels[i]);
    }
  }

  function Marq(c, tag) {
    var p, u, s, a, ims, ic, i, marqContent, cObj = this;
    this.mq = marqueeInit.ar[c];
    if (this.mq.random) {
      if (tag.getElementsByTagName && tag.getElementsByTagName('tr').length === 1 && tag.childNodes.length === 1) {
        randthem(tag.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0]);
      } else {
        randthem(tag);
      }
    }
    for (p in defaultconfig)
      if ((this.mq.hasOwnProperty && !this.mq.hasOwnProperty(p)) || (!this.mq.hasOwnProperty && !this.mq[p]))
        this.mq[p] = defaultconfig[p];

    this.mq.style.width = !this.mq.style.width || isNaN(parseInt(this.mq.style.width)) ? '100%' : this.mq.style.width;
    if (!tag.getElementsByTagName('img')[0])
      this.mq.style.height = !this.mq.style.height || isNaN(parseInt(this.mq.style.height)) ? tag.offsetHeight + 3 + 'px' : this.mq.style.height;
    else
      this.mq.style.height = !this.mq.style.height || isNaN(parseInt(this.mq.style.height)) ? 'auto' : this.mq.style.height;
    u = this.mq.style.width.split(/\d/);
    this.cw = this.mq.style.width ? [parseInt(this.mq.style.width), u[u.length - 1]] : ['a'];
    marqContent = trimTags(tag);
    tag.className = tag.id = '';
    tag.removeAttribute('class', 0);
    tag.removeAttribute('id', 0);
    if (ie)
      tag.removeAttribute('className', 0);
    tag.appendChild(tag.cloneNode(false));
    tag.className = ['marquee', c].join('');
    tag.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    this.c = tag.firstChild;
    this.c.appendChild(this.c.cloneNode(false));
    this.c.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    a = [
      [req1, this.c.style],
      [this.mq.style, this.c.style]
    ];
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > -1; --i)
      for (p in a[i][0])
        if ((a[i][0].hasOwnProperty && a[i][0].hasOwnProperty(p)) || (!a[i][0].hasOwnProperty))
          a[i][1][p.encamel()] = a[i][0][p];
    this.m = this.c.firstChild;
    if (this.mq.mouse === 'pause') {
      this.c.onmouseover = function() {
        cObj.mq.stopped = true;
      };
      this.c.onmouseout = function() {
        cObj.mq.stopped = false;
      };
    }
    this.m.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.m.style.left = '-10000000px';
    this.m.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
    if (ie5) this.c.firstChild.appendChild((this.m = document.createElement('nobr')));
    if (!this.mq.noAddedSpace)
      this.m.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\xa0'));
    for (i = 0; marqContent[i]; ++i)
      this.m.appendChild(marqContent[i]);
    if (ie5) this.m = this.c.firstChild;
    ims = this.m.getElementsByTagName('img');
    if (ims.length) {
      for (ic = 0, i = 0; i < ims.length; ++i) {
        ims[i].style.display = 'inline';
        if (!ims[i].alt && !this.mq.noAddedAlt) {
          ims[i].alt = (tTRE[3].exec(ims[i].src)) || ('Image #' + [i + 1]);
          if (!ims[i].title) {
            ims[i].title = '';
          }
        }
        ims[i].style.display = 'inline';
        ims[i].style.verticalAlign = ims[i].style.verticalAlign || 'top';
        if (typeof ims[i].complete === 'boolean' && ims[i].complete)
          ic++;
        else {
          ims[i].onload = ims[i].onerror = function() {
            if (++ic === ims.length)
              cObj.setup(c);
          };
        }
        if (ic === ims.length)
          this.setup(c);
      }
    } else this.setup(c)
  }

  Marq.prototype.setup = function(c) {
    if (this.mq.setup) return;
    this.mq.setup = this;
    var s, w, cObj = this,
      exit = 10000;
    if (this.c.style.height === 'auto')
      this.c.style.height = this.m.offsetHeight + 4 + 'px';
    this.c.appendChild(this.m.cloneNode(true));
    this.m = [this.m, this.m.nextSibling];
    if (typeof this.mq.initcontent === 'function') {
      this.mq.initcontent.apply(this.mq, [this.m]);
    }
    if (this.mq.mouse === 'cursor driven') {
      this.r = this.mq.neutral || 16;
      this.sinc = this.mq.inc;
      this.c.onmousemove = function(e) {
        cObj.mq.stopped = false;
        cObj.directspeed(e)
      };
      if (this.mq.moveatleast) {
        this.mq.inc = this.mq.moveatleast;
        if (this.mq.savedirection) {
          if (this.mq.savedirection === 'reverse') {
            this.c.onmouseout = function(e) {
              if (cObj.contains(e)) return;
              cObj.mq.inc = cObj.mq.moveatleast;
              cObj.mq.direction = cObj.mq.direction === 'right' ? 'left' : 'right';
            };
          } else {
            this.mq.savedirection = this.mq.direction;
            this.c.onmouseout = function(e) {
              if (cObj.contains(e)) return;
              cObj.mq.inc = cObj.mq.moveatleast;
              cObj.mq.direction = cObj.mq.savedirection;
            };
          }
        } else
          this.c.onmouseout = function(e) {
            if (!cObj.contains(e)) cObj.mq.inc = cObj.mq.moveatleast;
          };
      } else
        this.c.onmouseout = function(e) {
          if (!cObj.contains(e)) cObj.slowdeath();
        };
    }
    this.w = this.m[0].offsetWidth;
    this.m[0].style.left = 0;
    this.c.id = 'marq_kill_marg_bord';
    this.m[0].style.top = this.m[1].style.top = Math.floor((this.c.offsetHeight - this.m[0].offsetHeight) / 2 - oldie) + 'px';
    this.c.id = '';
    this.c.removeAttribute('id', 0);
    this.m[1].style.left = this.w + 'px';
    s = this.mq.moveatleast ? Math.max(this.mq.moveatleast, this.sinc) : (this.sinc || this.mq.inc);
    while (this.c.offsetWidth > this.w - s && --exit) {
      w = isNaN(this.cw[0]) ? this.w - s : --this.cw[0];
      if (w < 1 || this.w < Math.max(1, s)) {
        break;
      }
      this.c.style.width = isNaN(this.cw[0]) ? this.w - s + 'px' : --this.cw[0] + this.cw[1];
    }
    this.c.style.visibility = 'visible';
    this.runit();
  }

  Marq.prototype.slowdeath = function() {
    var cObj = this;
    if (this.mq.inc) {
      this.mq.inc -= 1;
      this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
        cObj.slowdeath();
      }, 100);
    }
  }

  Marq.prototype.runit = function() {
    var cObj = this,
      d = this.mq.direction === 'right' ? 1 : -1;
    if (this.mq.stopped || this.mq.stopMarquee) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        cObj.runit();
      }, 300);
      return;
    }
    if (this.mq.mouse != 'cursor driven')
      this.mq.inc = Math.max(1, this.mq.inc);
    if (d * parseInt(this.m[0].style.left) >= this.w)
      this.m[0].style.left = parseInt(this.m[1].style.left) - d * this.w + 'px';
    if (d * parseInt(this.m[1].style.left) >= this.w)
      this.m[1].style.left = parseInt(this.m[0].style.left) - d * this.w + 'px';
    this.m[0].style.left = parseInt(this.m[0].style.left) + d * this.mq.inc + 'px';
    this.m[1].style.left = parseInt(this.m[1].style.left) + d * this.mq.inc + 'px';

    setTimeout(function() {
      cObj.runit();
    }, 30 + (this.mq.addDelay || 0));
  }

  Marq.prototype.directspeed = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);
    var c = this.c,
      w = c.offsetWidth,
      l = c.offsetLeft,
      mp = (typeof e.pageX === 'number' ?
        e.pageX : e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft) - l,
      lb = (w - this.r) / 2,
      rb = (w + this.r) / 2;
    while ((c = c.offsetParent)) mp -= c.offsetLeft;
    this.mq.direction = mp > rb ? 'left' : 'right';
    this.mq.inc = Math.round((mp > rb ? (mp - rb) : mp < lb ? (lb - mp) : 0) / lb * this.sinc);
  }

  Marq.prototype.contains = function(e) {
    if (e && e.relatedTarget) {
      var c = e.relatedTarget;
      if (c === this.c) return true;
      while ((c = c.parentNode))
        if (c === this.c) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function resize() {
    for (var s, w, m, i = 0; i < marqueeInit.ar.length; ++i) {
      if (marqueeInit.ar[i] && marqueeInit.ar[i].setup) {
        m = marqueeInit.ar[i].setup;
        s = m.mq.moveatleast ? Math.max(m.mq.moveatleast, m.sinc) : (m.sinc || m.mq.inc);
        m.c.style.width = m.mq.style.width;
        m.cw[0] = m.cw.length > 1 ? parseInt(m.mq.style.width) : 'a';
        while (m.c.offsetWidth > m.w - s) {
          w = isNaN(m.cw[0]) ? m.w - s : --m.cw[0];
          if (w < 1) {
            break;
          }
          m.c.style.width = isNaN(m.cw[0]) ? m.w - s + 'px' : --m.cw[0] + m.cw[1];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function unload() {
    for (var m, i = 0; i < marqueeInit.ar.length; ++i) {
      if (marqueeInit.ar[i] && marqueeInit.ar[i].persist && marqueeInit.ar[i].setup) {
        m = marqueeInit.ar[i].setup;
        m.cookie.set(m.mq.uniqueid, m.m[0].style.left + ':' + m.m[1].style.left + ':' + m.mq.direction);
      }
    }
  }

  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
    window.addEventListener('unload', unload, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', resize);
    window.attachEvent('onunload', unload);
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="marquee" id="mycrawler">
  Those confounded friars dully buzz that faltering jay. An appraising tongue acutely causes our courageous hogs. Their fitting submarines deftly break your approving improvisations. Her downcast taxonomies actually box up those disgusted turtles.
</div>
```