# Marquee tag in React

Tags: reactjs, marquee

how to use marquee tag . its not supporting html tag in ReactJS. I have tried to import react-text-marquee still style is not reflecting

```html
public render(): React.ReactElement<IScrollTickerWebPartProps> {
        return ( 
           <div className={styles.panelStyle} >
             <br></br>
             <Marquee text="swetha">Test</Marquee>
             
             <br></br>
             
             <div className={styles.tableStyle} >  
                
                 {this.state.items.map(function(item,key){     
                   return (<div className={styles.rowStyle} key={key}> 
                       <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.Title}</div>   
                     </div>); 
                 })} 
                        
             </div> 
           </div> 
       ); 
     }
```

Comment: There is no in-built JSX tag for `<Marquee>` html tag. Specified html tags respective to JSX are defined in react docs

Comment: JSX supports the vast majority of HTML tags: https://react-cn.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html

Comment: oh how to use it in jSX?

Comment: @tombraider I am not able to use it in JSX.

Answer (score 3):

In React Js, html marquee tag works.
You don't need to import any component.

Example

```html
public render(): React.ReactElement<IScrollTickerWebPartProps> {
        return ( 
           <div className={styles.panelStyle} >
             <br></br>
             <marquee style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '3em' }}>Test</marquee>
             
             <br></br>
             
             <div className={styles.tableStyle} >  
                
                 {this.state.items.map(function(item,key){     
                   return (<div className={styles.rowStyle} key={key}> 
                       <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.Title}</div>   
                     </div>); 
                 })} 
                        
             </div> 
           </div> 
       ); 
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Really simple fix; you've used a capital M in "Marquee". As a result of this, React is attempting to find a component called `Marquee` and failing. Simply change that to a little `m`, remove your prop and you'll be golden.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/h9fyvpwj/2/

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <marquee>Test</marquee>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Bear in mind, the `marquee` tag is now obsolete and you should refrain from using it where possible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee.

Comment: I get this error. Property 'marquee' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

Comment: I am trying to add this in JSX file shld I import anythng?

Comment: Going to guess that is a Typescript error. It is correct, JSX does not support `marquee` as an intrinsic element. React will still render it but it does not officially support it. You'll need to edit your Typescript to prevent it from erroring. Better yet, drop the `marquee` element altogether as it is now obsolete.

Comment: You can achieve a marquee effect using pure CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233033/css3-marquee-effect

Answer (score 1):

> Note − The  tag deprecated in HTML5. Do not use this element,
> instead you can use JavaScript and CSS to create such effects.

If you try to use it, you will get this warning in `typescript`

```
Property 'marquee' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'
```

Easiest way is to use [react-ticker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ticker). in your case you could create a component

```
import Ticker from "react-ticker"

const Marquee = ({children}) => {
  return (
    // wrap it to controll css better
    <div>
      <Ticker offset={80}>
        { () =>
          <div >
            {children}
          </div>
        }
      </Ticker>
    </div>
  )
}
```

use it anywhere you need like this:

```
<Marquee>
  {this.state.items.map(function (item, key) {
    return (
      <div className={styles.rowStyle} key={key}>
        <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.Title}</div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</Marquee>;
```

Comment: Unsupported/unmaintained. This is why I hate adding dependencies for things that shouldn't need dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the HTML `marquee` like this:

```
<marquee
    behavior='scroll'
    scrollamount='20'
    width='50%'
    direction='right'
    height='50px'
 >
    this is a news flash....
</marquee>
```