# How to pause marquee mouseIn and continue on on mouseOut?

Tags: javascript, marquee

I am attempting to have a marquee pause on hover and continue on mouseOut

I tried by including this but it does not work

```
marquee.hover(
  function() {
   go = false;
  },
function() {
    go = true;
  }
);
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here?

```
$(function() {

var marquee = $("#marquee"); 
marquee.css({"overflow": "hidden", "width": "100%"});

    marquee.hover(
function() {
   go = false;
  },
function() {
    go = true;
  }
);

// wrap "My Text" with a span (IE doesn't like divs inline-block)
marquee.wrapInner("<span>");
marquee.find("span").css({ "width": "50%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align":"center" }); 
marquee.append(marquee.find("span").clone()); // now there are two spans with "My Text"

marquee.wrapInner("<div>");
marquee.find("div").css("width", "200%");

var reset = function() {
    $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
    $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 28000, 'linear', reset);
};

reset.call(marquee.find("div"));
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a marquee effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233033/how-can-i-create-a-marquee-effect) or http://jsfiddle.net/MaY5A/1437/ for CSS-only options

Comment: That is a css3 marquee this is Javascript

Comment: is there a reason it needs to be done via JS? It's likely easier and more efficient to do in CSS alone.

Comment: Yes because this JS specifically makes the content appear on the right side of the broswer the second it exits on the left whereas css3 has to exit all the content out of the left side before it comes out of the right again

Comment: Does your solution need to handle dynamic widths for both the marquee box and the content? What happens if the text is more narrow than the div it's scrolling through - is the text listed multiple times? i.e. if the marquee box is 800px wide and the content is only 300px - is the content triplicated to fill the box? This is a specific requirement that should be edited into your question.